# Catching modal UIWebView links touches

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I have a view controller and I am intercepting the touches on links within the web views it manages.

My main view controller has this method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 

{
    //I can see this request come in upon a touch
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"raw: %@", urlString);

    //do some stuff (like figure out what capturedFilename is) 
    ExplainViewController *explanation = [[ExplainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExplainViewController" bundle:nil file:capturedFilename];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:explanation animated:YES];
}
```

And this loads a modal view properly.
ExplainViewController has a webView itself.  **When a user touches a link within ExplainViewConroller I'd like to handle that request too (and present another modal view)**.

ExplainViewController has this but I get no log activity from either method (the following nor the previous):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"raw: %@", urlString);
}
```

**I want to know where this link touch request is going and how I can intercept it.**

Both mentioned view controllers are using this in their .h
    `<UIWebViewDelegate`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that both view controllers conform to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, but is the delegate outlet of the UIWebView in the nib for `ExplainViewController.h` set to an instance of `ExplainViewController`. It will not call the method unless the `UIWebView` delegate property is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

    BrowserController *browserController = [[BrowserController alloc] initWithUrl:request.URL.absoluteString];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browserController];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController: navController animated:YES];
    [browserController release];
    [navController release];

    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```